# how to disable spell checking when entry password in edit text android

Tags: android

i am entering the text in edit text in some of mobile spell checking is supported in some not ,i have htc so it's doing spell check when i enter text in edit text so how to disable it for edit text android?
thanks...

xml for edit text is

```
<EditText 

 android:layout_marginTop="125dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dip"  
 android:id="@+id/editText2" 
 android:layout_height="40dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you define `android:inputType="textPassword"` then it automatically shutdown such spell checking feature.